# Заливка карты на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, яндекс-карта-api

При редактировании карты есть заливка, после перехода по ссылке заливка пропадает, с чем может быть связано?[image: Изображение после публикации карты]

[[image: Изображение карты в процессе редактирования2]

Comment: См https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6688/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-wordpress